# Postgresql 8.4 Autoincrement issue

Tags: laravel, postgresql

Hi I am using Postgresql 8.4 with a Laravel api.

I am getting the following error from Laravel when I am trying to add a new record:

```
Unique violation: 7 ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "yards_pkey"
```

From research I believe this is because the sequence is out of sync due to importing to the Yards table.

I have tried resetting the sequence with the following:

```
SELECT setval('yards_id_seq', (SELECT MAX(id) from "yards"));
```

But keep getting a Permission error:

```
ERROR:  permission denied for sequence yards_id_seq
```

I have tried fixing the permissions with the following:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON yards TO username;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SEQUENCE yards_id_seq TO username;
```

But neither of these works. How can I set the correct permissons for my user so I can fix the sequence?

Comment: Are you using "username" as user? Maybe try the setval() as a superuser.

Comment: Oh, and upgrade the 8.4 to something more recent. That version is out of support for a very long time.